# Cutting Paulownia wood with a jigsaw

Tags: cutting, jigsaw

Would a jigsaw be a suitable tool for cutting Paulownia wood across the grain?  If so, what sort of blade should I use for the job.  If not, what would be the best way of going about it?  The material I want to cut is 18mm thick.  I'd much appreciate any tips.

Comment: A jigsaw, where available, is fine for doing cuts along or across the grain (or both, curved cuts, one of the things jigsaws are ideal for). But alternatively any cut in wood, no matter what length or the thickness of the material, is possible using hand saws if you have the right types. So hand sawing should always be considered an option. What length of cuts do you need to do?

Comment: I need to cut several boards that are 300 - 400mm in width.  I was considering using a jigsaw purely in the interests of speed.  Paulownia is a rather special wood - as light as balsa but a whole lot stronger - so I wondered if the idea is not just downright dumb

Comment: Doing some test cuts using the blade or blades you currently have available would be a good starting point regardless of any Answers that might get posted here. You can see what the quality of cut is like firsthand in the wood you have there rather than someone with no experience cutting that wood specifically given more generic advice (which may or may not apply closely to paulownia). [contd]

Comment: If splintering is shown to be an issue on one face you can do all your cuts so that this becomes the non-show face. If both faces splinter more than is desirable then there are various steps that can be taken to help improve things, including taping the proposed cut line (then you saw through the tape) and better, scribing the cut line deeply before sawing using a sharp marking knife or craft knife. This severs the surface fibres so they can't tear free.

Comment: Thank you for some very useful tips - particuarly the on re scribing.  Write this up as an answer and I will accept + upvote it

Comment: Welcome for the tips. I won't write those up as an Answer here because they don't directly respond to the Question and as much as possible Answers should do that, but thanks anyway :-)

Comment: I don't know how good a jigsaw is for cutting Paulownia, but be aware that a jigsaw is not a particularly great tool for cutting straight lines - a circular saw is much better.